# If checkbox :checked more than 3 last one should unchecked

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, click

I have 6 `input[type="checkbox"]`.

User can select only 3 checkbox at a time.
If user selects the 4th checkbox then last checked(3rd checkbox) should unchecked.

Find image attachment for better understanding.

[image]

Meanwhile, if User selects 5th last selected (4th) should deselect.

As, I'm not able to create this logic so that I made fiddle demo in which if selected more than 3. The current one is not getting selected.

**[Find fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/usx8Lkc5/1/)**

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(e) {
var num_checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
if (num_checked > 3) { 
  $(e.target).prop('checked', false);
}
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to store reference to the last selected checkbox. Maybe like this:

```js
var lastChecked;

var $checks = $('input:checkbox').click(function(e) {
    var numChecked = $checks.filter(':checked').length;
    if (numChecked > 3) {
        alert("sorry, you have already selected 3 checkboxes!");
        lastChecked.checked = false;
    }
    lastChecked = this;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="" /> <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="" /> <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="" /> <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="" /> <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="" /> <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="" />
```

I also improved code a little by caching checkbox collection in variable so you don't re-query DOM again and again. `:checkbox` selector is handy too.

Comment: instead of `change` why use `click` when you are dealing with checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like fllowing.

```js
var last;
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 3) {
            $(last).prop('checked', false);
        }
        last = this;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var checked = [];
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(e) {
    var num_checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
    if (num_checked > 3) {
        checked[checked.length - 1].prop('checked', false);
        checked.pop();
    }
    if($.inArray($(this), checked) < 0){
        checked.push($(this));
    }
});
```

Check this out, the last will everytime change.

Comment: dsfq and Azim have given very good answer. Your answer is nice too. Thanks everyone.