# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I have 6 input checkboxes and if checkboxes are checked more than 3 the last one gets unchecked. For better understanding refer my previous **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35195235/if-checkbox-checked-more-than-3-last-one-should-unchecked)**. Which is solved.

Now, I have another problem, Now 3 checkboxes are checked already by `Math.random`. On click of any unchecked checkbox. I'm getting error in console.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop' of undefined

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/usx8Lkc5/13/)**

code below:

```
var random_checked = $("input[type=checkbox]").get().sort(function(){ 
    return Math.round(Math.random())-0.6; //so we get the right +/- combo
}).slice(0,3);
$(random_checked).prop('checked', true);



var checked = [];
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(e) {
    var num_checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
    if (num_checked > 3) {
        checked[checked.length - 1].prop('checked', false);
        checked.pop();
    }
    if($.inArray($(this), checked) < 0){
        checked.push($(this));
    }
});
```

Comment: `checked[checked.length - 1]` is undefined

Comment: To get rid of error check for length of checked array : if (num_checked > 3 && checked.length > 0) { ---- https://jsfiddle.net/usx8Lkc5/15/

Comment: It is defined. If I just remove `match.random` or by default selection then it works. see https://jsfiddle.net/usx8Lkc5/14/.

Comment: @zaki.. Your solution is good. it's works but at the same time 4 checkboxes should not be selected. If 4th one gets selected then the last one should get deselect at the same time. see https://jsfiddle.net/usx8Lkc5/16/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the below code

```
var checked = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(){
 return $(this);
}).get(); // First change
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(e) {
    var num_checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
    if (num_checked > 3) {
         $(checked.pop()).prop('checked', false);// Second change
    }
    if($.inArray($(this), checked) < 0){
        checked.push($(this));
    }
});
```

**[DEMO FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/usx8Lkc5/17/)**

**Changes Made**

► Stored the currently checked elements to an array using

```
var checked = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(){
 return $(this);
}).get();
```

► `$(checked.pop())` is used to select the last inserted element.

**Why your code was not working?**

As per you code `var checked = [];` will be empty at the initial stage. So `checked[checked.length - 1]` will become undefined.

Comment: That's really cool.. Thanks man for not just solving the issue but also explaining the reason behind my error..

Comment: Always glad to here that `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You should push initial items in checked list.

```
$(random_checked).each(function(){
    console.log($(this));
    checked.push($(this));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/usx8Lkc5/18/

Answer (score 1):

This one works, just simply adding lastChecked = random_checked[2]; so that your lastChecked is defined.

```
var random_checked = $("input[type=checkbox]").get().sort(function(){ 
 var test = Math.round(Math.random())-0.6;
 return test; //so we get the right +/- combo
}).slice(0,3);

$(random_checked).prop('checked', true);
    lastChecked = random_checked[2];
var $checks = $('input:checkbox').click(function(e) {
    var numChecked = $checks.filter(':checked').length;
    if (numChecked > 2) {
        alert("sorry, you have already selected 3 checkboxes!");
        lastChecked.checked = false;
    }
    lastChecked = this;
});
```